# IAsyncOperation in delegate, is it possible?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, c#-5.0

```
public delegate string IAsyncOperation<IEnumerable<string>> ThisReceiveStringHandler();
...
public event ThisReceiveStringHandler ThisReceiveString;
```

I'm trying do a async event, but but the above code don't work. 
Could anyone tell me if there is any possibility of creating asynchronous events? Or if there is a more elegant approach?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? What *does* the code do? And could you explain what exactly are you trying to do? *Why* are you trying to do this? Also, while possible, it's very unusual to have an event that returns something.

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing your own async operations? Use Task for that unless you are developing Windows RT components. As svick says, events do not typically return, they are merely fired. Sometimes you don't event want to know if they are done.

What do you want to do? Fire an event whenever a string is received? You should use Rx for that (unless string is received at most once, then use Task). If you give the remainder of your code - the part which fires the event and the part which receives the event, I can assist you in rewriting it.

How do you receive a string? Via HttpClient or? You can use TaskCompletionSource to translate one asynchronous method into an another.